# The interactive feature input to set extent - is there way to get the schema from one of the input layers

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

i created script that run some task 
i need for the user to draw the extent on screen 
when i define the parameter for the tools 
the extent defined as feature set and i need to add layer to use it schema
how can i define it so the schema is the same as one of the input polygon layer ?

the tool wont always be on the same PC or network

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.